# Google sheets query function. Use where clause with string that includes apostrophe

Tags: google-sheets

How do you use a string with an apostrophe in the `where` clause of the `query` function?

I want to be able to filter my query with a string that includes an apostrophe like this.

```
=QUERY(D:E;"select E where D = 'this string's apostrophe breaks my code'";0)
```

[image]

Anyone know how to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by placing two sets of double quotes around the string you wish to use in your `where` clause.

For example:

```
=QUERY(D:E;"select E where D = ""this string's apostrophe breaks my code""";0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the criteria in double quotes:

```
"select E where D = ""this string's apostrophe breaks my code"""
```